# Ignore image urls in wp_query search

Tags: wp-query, search, attachments

I'm doing a keyword search using wp_query as so:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 's=' . $_GET['s'] );
```

It is returning a post that has `$_GET['s']` in one of its image URLs, and I don't want this to happen. I'd like to exclude any attachment URL from the search.

Is this possible using the wp_query arguments? Maybe a way to only search the title/body of a post?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add [`post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Type_Parameters) argument like this:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    's'         => $_GET['s'],
    'post_type' => array( 'post', /* add more post types if need be */ ),
) );
```

Read [the codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query) about `WP_Query` class for more information.

Comment: Using the 'post' post_type still doesn't filter out the images that are embedded within the post. Is there anyway to only search text within a post? Not the HTML itself?

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?